# Python Unit Test Whole-Module Setup

Tags: python, pycharm, python-unittest

I am attempting to test a webapp with Selenium and Python. The application has a database backup utility that is quite handy. Currently, I have one large class `RegressionTest(unittest.TestCase)` and it utilizes `setUpClass()` and `tearDownClass()` to perform the database backup before and restoration after the test finishes. It's all working great, but I'd *really* like split these tests into multiple classes (with each test class having its own file) but I can't find a good way to do this without duplicating the backup/restore action.

Further complicating things, I want add the following restrictions:

This needs to be invokable both on my TeamCity CI server (currently using `python3 -m teamcity.unittestpy`, but I'm flexible so long as I continue to get test reporting) and via PyCharm's standard unit test run configuration. Unfortunately, when invoked through PyCharm, `'__main__' == __name__` seems to evaluate to `False`, which rules out the possibility of a context manager like this:

```
if '__main__' == __name__:
  with BackupManager():
    if seleniumutils.is_running_under_teamcity():
      runner = TeamcityTestRunner()
    else:
      runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    unittest.main(testRunner=runner)
```

Here's the line that PyCharm is executing:
`/usr/bin/python3 /Path/To/PyCharm/Installation/helpers/pycharm/_jb_unittest_runner.py --path /Path/To/Project/Test/Code/testregression.py`
And here is the exact version of `_jb_unittest_runner.py` in the version of PyCharm that I'm using right now: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/3486b93168677dbc2519a78f472039bc50ca78be/python/helpers/pycharm/_jb_unittest_runner.py

I can't think of anything that will allow me to do this. I thought maybe multiple inheritance could help, as ugly as that would be. But, I can't come up with any scenario in my head that wouldn't leave each test being invoked a minimum of two times.

So, can anyone come up with a solution that allows me to perform an action exactly once before and after my tests?

Comment: Have you considered instead of messing with your running dev database, pointing your tests at a different database (an in-memory sqlite, another schema in your dev db, or even a second docker container that gets spun up by your test script?)

Comment: I like your idea, but that would change the entire way I test, and slow down the test-code-repeat cycle a lot. Sure, I could script some of those steps but that's adding another layer of complexity that I'd prefer to avoid. Since these are selenium tests, there's no easy way to just swap a running app instance to a different db

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to run the database backup once per test module, you might consider the `setUpModule()` and `tearDownModule()` functions.

Python's `unittest` will execute `setUpModule()` and `tearDownModule()` functions once for each module when these are declared at the module level.

PyCharm will run these when configured with the unittestrunner and I would imagine TeamCity will too since it is using `unittest` under the covers.

Comment: I think that's exactly what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure what defines the boundary for a single "module." Are you able to explain that?

Comment: The boundary here would be the `.py` file that houses your test classes. So if you're planning on refactoring your large test class into separate modules (`.py` files), it would mean having separate`setUpModule()` and `tearDownModule()` functions defined in each.

Comment: That's a real bummer, and means its barely any better than using `setUpClass()` and `tearDownClass()`. I see my question did not explicitly state my desire to have one test class per file, so I'll go edit that.

Comment: You can put it in the __init__.py file in your test directory and get it run once per package as well.

Comment: Now THAT sounds like exactly what I'm looking for. Can you convert that to an answer and provide a link to the docs for that?

Comment: I'm not find any reference to `init.py`, and particularly no reference to `init.py` in relation to `unittest`. Are you referring to `__init__.py`? If so, that wouldn't give me restore functionality, would it?

Comment: I don't see any reference to it in the docs either, but we do have it in the in it.py files. It is possible that it is a nose test specific thing, so I would just recommend trying it. (Yeah, the underscores in the filename turned into italics)